# AdonisJS - Type Error in Controller Test for loginAs() function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, adonis.js, japa

I would need your help regarding a type error on the argument of the `loginAs()` function in a controller test.

Context: I have set up authentication for 2 different models (User & Facility), everything works perfectly via Postman calls. My Facility model can have multiple Offers, and an Offer belongs to a Facility. My controller test makes a request to this URL: `/api/v1/facilities/${facility.id}/offers`, it's a nested route, protected with Facility authentication and guard.

Here is my test code:

```js
import { test } from '@japa/runner'
import Facility from 'App/Models/Facility'
import { FacilityFactory } from 'Database/factories/FacilityFactory'
import { status, json } from '../../../shared-examples'

test.group('#GET /api/v1/facilities/:facility_id/offers', (group): void => {
  let facility: Facility

  group.each.setup(async (): Promise<void> => {
    facility = await FacilityFactory.with('offers', 20).create()
    await facility.load('offers')
  })

  test('returns 200 status', async ({ client }): Promise<void> => {
    const response = await client
      .get(`/api/v1/facilities/${facility.id}/offers`)
      .guard('facility')
      .loginAs(facility) // The type argument [Facility] is not assignable to the type parameter never

    status(response, 200)
  })
})
```

My test passes without issues, but I have an error during the build on `.loginAs(facility)`, which is as follows: `The type argument [Facility] is not assignable to the type parameter never`. Here is the typing of the `loginAs()` function: `loginAs(...args: never): ApiRequest` from Adonis.

I can't understand this error. Here is the link to the Adonis documentation for the usage of `loginAs()`: [Adonis Doc](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/testing/http-tests#authentication)

If you have any ideas, I'm all ears

Thank you very much